# Finding the matrices that represent the differentials of a chain complex generated by finite groups

Tags: algebraic-topology

We have for any semi-simplicial set $Y$ it's chain complex $C(Y)$ defined as $$C(Y)_r=\mathbb{Z}[Y_r]=\text{free abelian group on the set }Y_r$$ and $d(z)=\sum_{i=0}^{r}(-1)^if_i^*(z)$ for $z\in Y_r$, where $f_i:[r-1]\to [r]$ is the unique injective order-preserving map which has image $[r]\setminus[i]$.

Let all the sets $Y_r$ be finite, and choose a total ordering for each.

Now using these orderings, I am curious about how the matrices representing the maps $d_r:C(Y)_r\to C(Y)_{r-1}$ would look? Also, is there going to be any bounds on the entries of the matrices depending upon $r$?

Any help is much appreciated and please elaborate your statements.

Comment: Every $n$-simplex has $n+1$ faces, so each entry in the $n$th boundary matrix will be at most $n+1$. What other information are you hoping for? You can also use SageMath to look at some examples, if you don't want to compute them yourself.